# Add volume control to desktop panel indicator?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, indicator

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04 and I noticed that I'm no longer able to add a volume control to my desktop panels. When I right click the panel and choose "Add to panel" there is no longer a volume control in the list.

How do I add a volume control to my desktop panel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the the option from the list to add an "Indicator Applet".

This is because from Ubuntu 10.04 there has been a push for panel items to use a new system for panel items.

If adding the "Indicator Applet" appears to make no difference, you should try to install the package `indicator-sound` which contains the sound indicator.

Comment: The package name is indicator-sound if you want to add that to your answer.

Comment: The "Indicator Applet" seems to give me a sound volume control but it also gives me a email control. I don't even use desktop email... When I try install "indicator-sound" it says I already have the latest package but I can't find it individually in the list.

Comment: The "Indicator Applet" includes all your installed indicators (it is arguably a bug that you can't customise which indicators are shown more easily, I've certainly found this frustrating!). If you don't want the email control remove the `indicator-messages` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot fluteflute and Jorge Castro. I was also unable to see my Volume Indicator and installing the indicator-sound package brought it back. I certainly agree that it should be easier to customize the indicator applet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the volume control like in previous version (9.10 and earlier) of Ubuntu you'll need to edit a file.

Open the terminal and type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-volume-control-applet.desktop
```

In the file that opens, look for this line:

```
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

That line prevents the older volume control from showing on the panel. Change it by putting a # in front of it so it looks like:

```
#OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

Save the file then log out and back in and the volume control should be back.
If you find that you have 2 volume controls and you want to keep the older control, remove the app called "indicator-sound" via synaptic.